# Error when validating an XML file with XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to validate an XML file with XSD, but I get a "*Could not find schema information for the element 'xxx'*" for each element and attribute.

My C# code is:

```
public ReadeXmlFile(string FilePath)
{
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
    {
       IgnoreComments = true, 
       ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
       CheckCharacters=true,
       ValidationFlags= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings
    };
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += settings_ValidationEventHandler;
    var xsdReader = new XmlTextReader("KeyEmFileSchema.xsd");
    settings.Schemas.Add(null, xsdReader);

    using (var reader = XmlTextReader.Create(FilePath, settings))
    {
       while (reader.Read()){}
    }
}

void settings_ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
     Debug.WriteLine(e.Severity + " - " + e.Message);
}
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<keyem description="test"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
>
  <layout type="keyboard" height="300" width="300">
    <groupp text="rad 1">
      <key color="Black" macro="{ESC}10{ESC}43{MOUSERESET}" text="Ordi-\nnarie"/>
      <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}10{ESC}B0{MOUSERESET}" text="Släck\nskärm"/>
      <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n1"/>
      <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n2" icon="dfkhfkjsdhfkjdsf">
        <shift color="Blue"  macro="{ESC}1C{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Annan Skärm"/>
      </key>
      <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n3"/>
      <empty/>
      <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n4"/>
    </groupp>
    <group text="rad 2">
      <key color="Black" macro="{ESC}10{ESC}43{MOUSERESET}" text="Ordi-\nnarie"/>
      <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}10{ESC}B0{MOUSERESET}" text="Släck\nskärm"/>
      <group color ="Blue" text="test">
        <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n1"/>
        <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n2"/>
        <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n3"/>
      </group>
      <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n1"/>
      <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n2"/>
      <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n3"/>
      <empty/>
      <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n4"/>
    </group>
  </layout>
</keyem>
```

My XSD file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema id="FileSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation xml:lang="sv-se">Definition av layout</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>

  <!--Definition av attribut-->
  <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="text"        type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="height"      type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
  <xs:attribute name="width"       type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
  <xs:attribute name="type"        type="LayoutTypeSet" default="keyboard"/>
  <xs:attribute name="macro"       type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="icon"        type="xs:base64Binary"/>
  <xs:attribute name="color"       type="ColorType"/>

  <!--Definition av attributgrupp-->
  <xs:attributeGroup name="ShiftKeyAttributeGroup">
    <xs:attribute ref="color" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="macro" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="text"  use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="icon"  use="optional"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <!--Definition av root-->
  <xs:element name="keyem">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="layout" type="LayoutType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute ref="description" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <!--Definition av komplexa typer-->
  <xs:complexType name="GroupKeyType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="group" type="GroupType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="key"   type="KeyType"   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="LayoutType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="group" type="GroupType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="key"   type="KeyType"   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute ref="type"   use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="height" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="width"  use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="GroupType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="group" type="GroupType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="key"   type="KeyType"   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="empty" type="EmptyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute ref="text"  use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="color" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="EmptyType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="empty"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ShiftType">
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="ShiftKeyAttributeGroup"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="KeyType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="shift" type="ShiftType" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="ShiftKeyAttributeGroup"/>
  </xs:complexType>


  <!--Definition av enkla typer-->
  <xs:simpleType      name="ColorType">
    <xs:restriction   base="xs:string">
      <!--Regex för att antingen matcha färg angivet på formen #rrggbb eller som är skriven i klarspråk, t.ex. "Green"-->
      <xs:pattern     value="\#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}|[a-zA-Z]+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType      name="LayoutTypeSet">
    <xs:restriction   base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="keyboard"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="list"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined schema in the `KeyEmFileSchema.xsd` file you can use `schemaLocation` instead of `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`:

```
<keyem description="test"
      xmlns="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
>
```

which defines file name (it can be with the path if required) where the definition `http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd` can be found and used. Then you can use

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings ();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
settings.IgnoreComments = true;
settings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create (xmlFilePath, settings);
```

If you want you can additionally use `ValidationEventHandler`. Without the handler you will receive exception with the information about validation errors.

**UPDATED**: By the way after including of `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"` and `xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"` in the root element of your xml file you **will be seen already in Visual Studio Text Editor** the errors in your XML file:

1. Usage of the undeclared attribute `description` in `keyem` element.
2. Usage of all attributes in `layout` element which are also undeclared.
3. Usage of `groupp` element instead of `group`.

**UPDATED 2**: The requirement number 3: to replace `groupp` to `group` is clear. Because nobody commented my answer I suppose that somebody ask "what is wrong with attributes of the XML file?". OK I have to comment this more.

The problem in your XSD file is that you declare attributes as **NOT a part of some simple types, attribute group or attributes of some element**. You just declare some **"independent" attributes** and then use there per "ref" reference. It is in general possible, but this way require usage of ***qualified* attributes**. So if you make no changes in your schema the fixed version of your XML file will be following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<keyem xmlns="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
       a:description="test" xmlns:a="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
>
    <layout a:type="keyboard" a:height="300" a:width="300">
        <group a:text="rad 1">
            <key a:color="Black" a:macro="{ESC}10{ESC}43{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Ordi-\nnarie"/>
            <key a:color="Gray"  a:macro="{ESC}10{ESC}B0{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Släck\nskärm"/>
            <key a:color="Gray"  a:macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Skärm\n1"/>
            <key a:color="Gray"  a:macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Skärm\n2" a:icon="dfkhfkjsdhfkjdsf">
                <shift a:color="Blue"  a:macro="{ESC}1C{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Annan Skärm"/>
            </key>
            <key a:color="Gray"  a:macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Skärm\n3"/>
            <empty><empty/></empty>
            <key a:color="Gray"  a:macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Skärm\n4"/>
        </group>
        <group a:text="rad 2">
            <key a:color="Black" a:macro="{ESC}10{ESC}43{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Ordi-\nnarie"/>
            <key a:color="Gray"  a:macro="{ESC}10{ESC}B0{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Släck\nskärm"/>
            <group a:color ="Blue" a:text="test">
                <key a:color="Gray"  a:macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Skärm\n1"/>
                <key a:color="Gray"  a:macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Skärm\n2"/>
                <key a:color="Gray"  a:macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Skärm\n3"/>
            </group>
            <key a:color="Gray"  a:macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Skärm\n1"/>
            <key a:color="Gray"  a:macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Skärm\n2"/>
            <key a:color="Gray"  a:macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Skärm\n3"/>
            <empty><empty/></empty>
            <key a:color="Gray"  a:macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" a:text="Skärm\n4"/>
        </group>

</layout>
</keyem>
```

**A small remark**: `<empty>` element is wrong defined in your schema, so to follow the schema we have to use it like `<empty><empty/></empty>`.

Another version of possible changes (which you will probably prefer) is **to place all attributes in the definition of elements or attribute group**. Usage of simple types in your case seems me not needed. So the fixed version of the schema can be following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema id="FileSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation xml:lang="sv-se">Definition av layout</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>

  <!--Definition av attributgrupp-->
  <xs:attributeGroup name="ShiftKeyAttributeGroup">
    <xs:attribute name="color" type="ColorType"/>
    <xs:attribute name="macro" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="text"  type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="icon"  type="xs:base64Binary"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <!--Definition av root-->
  <xs:element name="keyem">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="layout" type="LayoutType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <!--Definition av komplexa typer-->
  <xs:complexType name="GroupKeyType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="group" type="GroupType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="key"   type="KeyType"   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="LayoutType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="group" type="GroupType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="key"   type="KeyType"   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="type"   type="LayoutTypeSet" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
    <xs:attribute name="width"  type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="GroupType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="group" type="GroupType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="key"   type="KeyType"   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="empty" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="text" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="color" type="ColorType"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ShiftType">
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="ShiftKeyAttributeGroup"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="KeyType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="shift" type="ShiftType" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="ShiftKeyAttributeGroup"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <!--Definition av enkla typer-->
  <xs:simpleType      name="ColorType">
    <xs:restriction   base="xs:string">
      <!--Regex för att antingen matcha färg angivet på formen #rrggbb eller som är skriven i klarspråk, t.ex. "Green"-->
      <xs:pattern     value="\#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}|[a-zA-Z]+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType      name="LayoutTypeSet">
    <xs:restriction   base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="keyboard"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="list"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

If we save the new schema in the file `KeyEmFileSchema1.xsd` then `KeyEmFileSchema.xml` file can be almost the same as you have before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<keyem xmlns="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd KeyEmFileSchema1.xsd"
       description="test"
>
    <layout type="keyboard" height="300" width="300">
        <group text="rad 1">
            <key color="Black" macro="{ESC}10{ESC}43{MOUSERESET}" text="Ordi-\nnarie"/>
            <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}10{ESC}B0{MOUSERESET}" text="Släck\nskärm"/>
            <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n1"/>
            <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n2" icon="dfkhfkjsdhfkjdsf">
                <shift color="Blue"  macro="{ESC}1C{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Annan Skärm"/>
            </key>
            <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n3"/>
            <empty/>
            <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n4"/>
        </group>
        <group text="rad 2">
            <key color="Black" macro="{ESC}10{ESC}43{MOUSERESET}" text="Ordi-\nnarie"/>
            <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}10{ESC}B0{MOUSERESET}" text="Släck\nskärm"/>
            <group color ="Blue" text="test">
                <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n1"/>
                <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n2"/>
                <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n3"/>
            </group>
            <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n1"/>
            <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n2"/>
            <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n3"/>
            <empty/>
            <key color="Gray"  macro="{ESC}1B{ESC}81{MOUSERESET}" text="Skärm\n4"/>
        </group>

</layout>
</keyem>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I knew that groupp was misspelled, it was a deliberate error I done to see if the validation worked (but forgot to correct it when I published this). And that I was careless with <empty> I discovered before.

When I designed the XSD file, I followed the advice in http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_example.asp. When I corrected the obvious errors, I could validate my xml file. I do not understand the problem with "qualified attributes".

Comment: @magol: I suggest that you look at the problem from the other side. I see from your code, that you use C# and Visual Studio. After I discovered one day the power of `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute I write always schema and then XML with the `xsi:schemaLocation`. I see immediately whether **my environment** understand what I write or not. If you try to use your schema in Visual Studio it understand the attributes which you defined only if there "qualified attributes". If is is a Microsoft bug you can't change it. So from the practical side you **because you use MS .NET** you should write for it.

Comment: @magol: The XML Schema defined in http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema is **very complex** One divided specification in two parts and one additional part 0 (which is not an official standard) **because it is so complex**. So it is much better to write so that different interpretation of XSD understand your schema correct. Be simple!

Comment: @magol: In the modified version of schema from my answer I used attribute groups which I find practical. If you define some simple type like `ColorType` or `LayoutTypeSet` I find is also very practical, but I don't see any **real advantage** of definition of  separate attribute like `macro` and use `ref` to it. So in my opinion the modified schema which I suggest is written mostly in your style (only without unbind attributes). Why not just use this way? All (inclusive .NET) will understand it. Where you see any disadvantage?

Comment: @magol: Sorry, that I write so much, but... You wrote, that you used http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_example.asp as a template. The example is really define a Schema **without a namespace** or with **no namespace** because one use no `targetNamespace` here. It is very important! Exactly for the case the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` is introduced (for schema with **no namespace**). In your schema use **do define** the schema target namespace so you **have to use** `xsi:schemaLocation` which are defined exactly for the case (see http://www.edankert.com/grammars/xsd.referencing.html).

Comment: I very much appreciate your thorough response. You have convinced me, and I choose to follow your recommendation. However, I have a small problem remains. My XML file and XSD file is not in the same location, and VS2010 complains about the line xsi:schemalocation="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd KeyEmFileSchema.xsd". It tries to find my xsd file in the same location as my xml fil. How can I make it find the xsd file. I do not want to hardcode the path in the xml file.

Comment: @magol: The `xsi:schemalocation` attribute has the form "namespace xsd-path". So If you have the `KeyEmFileSchema.xsd` not in the same directory you should change the path which are after the blank. For example `xsi:schemalocation="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd mySubDir/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"` will work. The path part of the `xsi:schemalocation` attribute you can write as a url form also.

Comment: So I can not tell Visual Studio where to search for the xsd file?

Comment: @magol: You can do this, but you should get Visual Studio information about the path of the xsd file. You can you either a relative path form like `xsi:schemalocation="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd mySubDir/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"` (if `KeyEmFileSchema.xsd` in in the subdrirectory `mySubDir` relative to the `KeyEmFileSchema.xml`) or use an absolute path form `xsi:schemalocation="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd FullXsdPath"`. I tried this just now in Visual Studio and it works without any problem. If I write a wrong path Visual Studio show  me an error, but with correct path - OK.

Answer (score 1):

according to your schema you have a wrong node inside of your xml :

```
<groupp text="rad 1">
```

Just group or key element could be inserted at that level.

Concerning your specific problem try to use the next root node inside your schema file :

```
<xs:schema id="FileSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
...
</xs:schema>
```